# How do I take a day of the year and 'bucket it' into weeks of the year in Microsoft SQL? Used in manufacturing scenarios for material requirements

Tags: sql-server, datediff, dateadd

I have a need to create a gross requirements report that takes how much supply and demand of a item in inventory from a start date onwards and 'buckets' it into different weeks of the year so that material planners know when they will need a item and if they have enough stock in inventory at that time.

As an example, today’s date (report date) is 8/27/08. The first step is to find the date for the Monday of the week the report date falls in. In this case, Monday would be 8/25/08. This becomes the first day of the first bucket. All transactions that fall before that are assigned to week #0 and will be summarized as the beginning balance for the report. The remaining buckets are calculated from that point. For the eighth bucket, there is no ending date so any transactions after that 8th bucket start date are considered week #8.

WEEK#   START DATE  END DATE
0.......None..........8/24/08
1.......8/25/08.......8/31/08
2.......9/1/08.........9/7/08
3.......9/8/08.........9/14/08
4.......9/15/08.......9/21/08
5.......9/22/08.......9/28/08
6.......9/29/08.......10/5/08
7.......10/06/08.....10/12/08
8.......10/13/08......None

How do I get the week #, start date, end date for a given date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get Monday for any given date in a week as:

```
DATEADD(d, 1 - DATEPART(dw, @date), @date)
```

and you can write a stored procedure with the following body

```
-- find Monday at that week
DECLARE @currentDate SMALLDATETIME
SELECT @currentDate = DATEADD(d, 1 - DATEPART(dw, @date), @date)

-- create a table and insert the first record
DECLARE @weekTable TABLE (Id INT, StartDate SMALLDATETIME, EndDate SMALLDATETIME)
INSERT INTO @weekTable VALUES (0, NULL, @currentDate)

-- increment the date
SELECT @currentDate = DATEADD(d, 1, @currentDate)

-- iterate for 7 more weeks
DECLARE @id INT
SET @id = 1
WHILE @id < 8
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @weekTable VALUES (@id, @currentDate, DATEADD(d, 6, @currentDate))
    SELECT @currentDate = DATEADD(ww, 1, @currentDate)
    SET @id = @id + 1
END

-- add the last record
INSERT INTO @weekTable VALUES (8, @currentDate, NULL)

-- select the values
SELECT Id 'Week #', StartDate 'Start Date', EndDate 'End Date'
FROM @weekTable
```

When I pass

```
@date = '20080827'
```

to this procedure, I get the following

```
Week #  Start Date     End Date
0   NULL                2008-08-24 00:00:00
1   2008-08-25 00:00:00 2008-08-31 00:00:00
2   2008-09-01 00:00:00 2008-09-07 00:00:00
3   2008-09-08 00:00:00 2008-09-14 00:00:00
4   2008-09-15 00:00:00 2008-09-21 00:00:00
5   2008-09-22 00:00:00 2008-09-28 00:00:00
6   2008-09-29 00:00:00 2008-10-05 00:00:00
7   2008-10-06 00:00:00 2008-10-12 00:00:00
8   2008-10-13 00:00:00 NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

I've always found it easiest and most efficient (for SQL Server) to construct a table with one row for every week into the future through your domain horizon; and join to that (with a "WHERE GETDATE() >= MONDATE AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE MONDATE < GETDATE())".

Anything you try to do with UDF's will be much less efficient and I find more difficult to use.

Comment: select * 
from dbo.fnGetDateRanges('d', '2006-01-01 11:10:00', '2006-01-05 08:00:00')  is not terribly hard to use ... in general I find the UDF performance to be good enough, also you can use the UDF to populate the horizon table

Comment: I have always found UDFs break SARG and TSQL date arithmetic needs to be mastered anyway. But good enough for building the table if you're not comfortable with TSQL date expressions. YYMV. :D

Comment: I have enough data (800,000 rows or so) and it's easy enough to switch this from creating a temp table at the start or using a UDF (built already) that I can test both ways to see which is faster.

Comment: Don't make it a temp table - make it permanent, so it can be indexed properly. Let us know what you find out :)

Comment: No argument here, UDF is less efficient but depending on the problem they can be efficient enough with the added benefit that the code can sometimes read better, they are most certainly more efficient than doing stuff one row at a time ...

Comment: I predict a breathtaking difference in performance, but we'll see. :)

Comment: @ie dorfer, #temp table support indexes ... only issue is that the execution plan will get recompiled in the proc, @Jaydel, at 800,000 UDF does not stand a chance, you better create a temp table with indexes or a fixed table

Comment: Sure it supports indexes, but why take the time to create them? Plus it makes the execution unit more complex. You can even put it into the "model" database if you want to get at it from anywhere.

Comment: @ie I think that if you can create a perm table and work with it then good, it you can not indexed temp tables are good enough,if you need to split into ranges dynamically based on user input eg(Mon 1:22, Tue 1:22) temp tables are very effective cause the dateadd statement on your perm will not sarg

Comment: Make that "put it into the "master" database".

I predict less than 10 sec. - maybe a lot less.

Answer (score 0):

--SQL sets the first day of the week as sunday and for our purposes we want it to be Monday.
--This command does that.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1

DECLARE 
    @ReportDate DATETIME, 

    @Weekday INTEGER, 
    @NumDaysToMonday INTEGER, 
    @MondayStartPoint DATETIME,
    @MondayStartPointWeek INTEGER,
    @DateToProcess DATETIME,
    @DateToProcessWeek INTEGER,
    @Bucket VARCHAR(50),
    @DaysDifference INTEGER,
    @BucketNumber INTEGER,
    @NumDaysToMondayOfDateToProcess INTEGER,
    @WeekdayOfDateToProcess INTEGER,
    @MondayOfDateToProcess DATETIME,
    @SundayOfDateToProcess DATETIME

SET @ReportDate = '2009-01-01'
print @ReportDate

SET @DateToProcess = '2009-01-26'
--print @DateToProcess

SET @Weekday = (select DATEPART ( dw , @ReportDate ))
--print @Weekday

--print DATENAME(dw, @ReportDate)

SET @NumDaysToMonday = 
    (SELECT
      CASE 
         WHEN @Weekday =  1 THEN 0
         WHEN @Weekday =  2 THEN 1
         WHEN @Weekday =  3 THEN 2
         WHEN @Weekday =  4 THEN 3
         WHEN @Weekday =  5 THEN 4
         WHEN @Weekday =  6 THEN 5
         WHEN @Weekday =  7 THEN 6
      END)

--print @NumDaysToMonday

SET @MondayStartPoint =  (SELECT DATEADD (d , -1*@NumDaysToMonday, @ReportDate))
--print @MondayStartPoint

SET @DaysDifference = DATEDIFF ( dd , @MondayStartPoint , @DateToProcess )
--PRINT @DaysDifference

SET @BucketNumber = @DaysDifference/7
--print @BucketNumber

----Calculate the start and end dates of this bucket------
PRINT 'Start Of New Calc'

print @DateToProcess

SET @WeekdayOfDateToProcess = (select DATEPART ( dw , @DateToProcess ))
print @WeekdayOfDateToProcess

SET @NumDaysToMondayOfDateToProcess= 
    (SELECT
      CASE 
         WHEN @WeekdayOfDateToProcess =  1 THEN 0
         WHEN @WeekdayOfDateToProcess =  2 THEN 1
         WHEN @WeekdayOfDateToProcess =  3 THEN 2
         WHEN @WeekdayOfDateToProcess =  4 THEN 3
         WHEN @WeekdayOfDateToProcess =  5 THEN 4
         WHEN @WeekdayOfDateToProcess =  6 THEN 5
         WHEN @WeekdayOfDateToProcess =  7 THEN 6
      END)

print @NumDaysToMondayOfDateToProcess
SET @MondayOfDateToProcess =  (SELECT DATEADD (d , -1*@NumDaysToMondayOfDateToProcess, @DateToProcess))
print @MondayOfDateToProcess   ---This is the start week

SET @SundayOfDateToProcess = (SELECT DATEADD (d , 6, @MondayOfDateToProcess))
PRINT @SundayOfDateToProcess
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see with the one bucket at a time approach is that its hard to make it scale,

If you join into a user defined function you will get better performance, you could use [this a a starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196415/date-ranges-in-t-sql)

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify that I would put it in a user function.  it would make the parent procedure very messy if not!  I like the thought of putting the bucket ranges, as per comments in your post suggest into a temp table and then querying off of that instead of calling the function over and over.

Comment: make sure you add proper indexes to the temp table as well otherwise this may go pear shape.

Comment: NO temp table - permanent indexed table. Both UDFs and temp tables are bad mojo. (It used to be that UDF's were essentially SPs, and you ended up calling an SP per row - ugly though "compiled". Hopefully they've mitigated that a bit.)

Comment: I'm curious to see what the performance difference is between an indexed temp table and an indexed permanent table... it should only amount to the time it create the table, index it and recompile the plan. Usually for these kind of reports you are looking at many seconds of execution time

Comment: The primary benefit is a simplified execution unit. See other similar note.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a combination of DATEPART(year, date-column) and DATEPART(week, date-column) and group by these values.  This works if the week in [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) is aligned on Mondays as ISO 8601 requires.  In outline:

```
SELECT DATEPART(year, date_column) AS yyyy,
       DATEPART(week, date_column) AS ww,
       ...other material as required...
    FROM SomeTableOrOther
    WHERE ...appropriate filters...
    GROUP BY yyyy, ww -- ...and other columns as necessary...
```