# I Need All Dates in Result Exclude Sunday

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I Need All Dates In Result Exclude Sunday:

> Input : Start Date = 2016-07-01 and End Date = 2016-07-31

```
S_No    Dates
1   01-07-2016
2   02-07-2016
3   04-07-2016
4   05-07-2016
5   06-07-2016
6   07-07-2016
7   08-07-2016
8   09-07-2016
9   11-07-2016
10  12-07-2016
11  13-07-2016
12  14-07-2016
13  15-07-2016
14  16-07-2016
15  18-07-2016
16  19-07-2016
17  20-07-2016
18  21-07-2016
19  22-07-2016
20  23-07-2016
21  25-07-2016
22  26-07-2016
23  27-07-2016
24  28-07-2016
25  29-07-2016
26  30-07-2016
```

I Need Result Like This. If I am giving input Input : `Start Date = 2016-06-01 and End Date = 2016-06-30`. All Dates Should Come in June'16 Exclude Sunday.

Kindly help me ?

Comment: Show us some code, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this one

```
WITH mycte AS
 (
   SELECT CAST('2016-06-01' AS DATETIME) DateValue
   UNION ALL
   SELECT  DateValue + 1
   FROM    mycte   
   WHERE   DateValue + 1 < '2016-07-01'
 )

 SELECT  DateValue
 FROM    mycte
 WHERE ((DATEPART(dw, DateValue) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (1)
 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

the output will be..

```
DateValue
2016-06-01 00:00:00.000
2016-06-02 00:00:00.000
2016-06-03 00:00:00.000
2016-06-04 00:00:00.000
2016-06-06 00:00:00.000
2016-06-07 00:00:00.000
2016-06-08 00:00:00.000
2016-06-09 00:00:00.000
2016-06-10 00:00:00.000
2016-06-11 00:00:00.000
2016-06-13 00:00:00.000
2016-06-14 00:00:00.000
2016-06-15 00:00:00.000
2016-06-16 00:00:00.000
2016-06-17 00:00:00.000
2016-06-18 00:00:00.000
2016-06-20 00:00:00.000
2016-06-21 00:00:00.000
2016-06-22 00:00:00.000
2016-06-23 00:00:00.000
2016-06-24 00:00:00.000
2016-06-25 00:00:00.000
2016-06-27 00:00:00.000
2016-06-28 00:00:00.000
2016-06-29 00:00:00.000
2016-06-30 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the given query,

here `dw` in `datepart()` function indicates the "week day".
You want to exclude Sunday so write 1 in the condition in where clause.

Query:

```
select S_No, Dates
from table_name 
where datepart(dw,Dates) <>1 and Dates >='2016-06-01' and Dates<='2016-06-30'
```

So according to this query you will get all the dates between `2016-06-01` and `2016-06-30` excluding sundays.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a query that returns dates excluding Sunday try this:

```
declare @dateStart date
declare @dateEnd date

set datefirst 7 -- Setting Sunday as firstday of the week

set @dateStart = cast('2016-06-01' as date) -- Maybe as paramters?
set @dateEnd = cast('2016-06-30' as date)



;WITH T AS (SELECT @dateStart as d union all
            SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,d) from T where d<@dateEnd)
select *
  from T
where datepart(WEEKDAY,d) <> 1
```

**Output**

```
d
2016-06-01
2016-06-02
2016-06-03
2016-06-04
2016-06-06
2016-06-07
2016-06-08
2016-06-09
2016-06-10
2016-06-11
2016-06-13
2016-06-14
2016-06-15
2016-06-16
2016-06-17
2016-06-18
2016-06-20
2016-06-21
2016-06-22
2016-06-23
2016-06-24
2016-06-25
2016-06-27
2016-06-28
2016-06-29
2016-06-30
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a table of integers:

```
SELECT TOP 1000000
        IDENTITY(INT,1,1) as N
   INTO dbo.NumbersTable
   FROM Master.dbo.SysColumns
```

Create a table for range of dates

```
DECLARE @DaysFromStart int
DECLARE @StartDate datetime
SET @StartDate = '10/01/2008'

SET @DaysFromStart  = (SELECT (DATEDIFF(dd,@StartDate,GETDATE()) + 1))

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableOfDates](
    [fld_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TableOfDates] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [fld_date] ASC
)WITH FILLFACTOR = 99 ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT INTO
     dbo.TableOfDates
SELECT 
      DATEADD(dd,nums.n - @DaysFromStart ,CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() as FLOAT)) as DateTime)) as FLD_Date
FROM dbo.NumbersTable nums

SELECT MIN(FLD_Date) FROM dbo.TableOfDates
SELECT MAX(FLD_Date) FROM dbo.TableOfDates
```

The final query for you to use:

```
SELECT FLD_Date FROM TableOfDates (NOLOCK) WHERE FLD_Date >= '2016-07-01' AND FLD_Date <= '2016-07-31' AND DATENAME(dw,FLD_Date) <> 'Sunday'
```

Reference: [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196415/date-ranges-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 0):

solution to your problem is as given below :

```
DECLARE @START_DATE DATETIME='2:57 PM 7/01/2016',@END_DATE DATETIME='2:57 PM 7/26/2016'


WHILE(@START_DATE<=@END_DATE)
BEGIN
IF(DATENAME(WEEKDAY,@START_DATE)<>'Sunday')
BEGIN
   PRINT @START_DATE --Modify code according to your need.
END
SELECT @START_DATE=DATEADD(D,1,@START_DATE)
END
```

Result :

```
Jul  1 2016  2:57PM
Jul  2 2016  2:57PM
Jul  4 2016  2:57PM
Jul  5 2016  2:57PM
Jul  6 2016  2:57PM
Jul  7 2016  2:57PM
Jul  8 2016  2:57PM
Jul  9 2016  2:57PM
Jul 11 2016  2:57PM
Jul 12 2016  2:57PM
Jul 13 2016  2:57PM
Jul 14 2016  2:57PM
Jul 15 2016  2:57PM
Jul 16 2016  2:57PM
Jul 18 2016  2:57PM
Jul 19 2016  2:57PM
Jul 20 2016  2:57PM
Jul 21 2016  2:57PM
Jul 22 2016  2:57PM
Jul 23 2016  2:57PM
Jul 25 2016  2:57PM
Jul 26 2016  2:57PM
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM tableName
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2016-06-01 03:13:45.040' AND '2016-06-30 03:13:45.040' AND  DATEPART(dw,Date)<>1